# Why do lipids decrease in viscosity with increasing temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heat

Is the answer simply that the carbon bonds break up and that the molecules get smaller?

Comment: Generally, all liquids  have decreasing viscosity with T, for water based liquids there is a rule of thumb 3% per 1 deg C.// there are special exceptions due internal effects.

Answer (score 2):

NO ! The carbon bonds do break up when increasing the temperature up to very high temperatures. But this effect, called pyrolysis, is negligible around room temperature. It starts at temperatures much higher than $100$°C, and it is not reversible, as the viscosity does change but the chemical composition also changes. So the viscosity of heated and pyrolyzed liquids (and then cooled down) is not comparable to the viscosity of the non-heated liquid.

To close the discussion, the decrease of viscosity due to increasing the temperature is a general phenomena, observed with all liquids, lipids or not lipids.